# Image pre-procesisng with dataframe

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I have about 1000 images in a cvs file. I have already managed to put those images in my Python programm by doing the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./Testes_small.csv")

# Creates the dataframe 
training_set = pd.DataFrame({'Images': training_imgs,'Labels': training_labels})

train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_dataGen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = training_set, directory="",
                                                   x_col="Images",  y_col="Labels",     
                                                   class_mode="categorical", 
                                                   target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=32)
##Steps to plot the images
imgs,labels = next(train_generator)

for i in range(batch_size):   # range de 0 a 31
    image = imgs[i]
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

So now I have the `train_generator` variable of type `python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataframeIterator` Its size is (32,224,224,3).

In the function `ImageDataGenerator` I want to put my own preprocessing function to resize the images. I want to do this because I have some rectangular images that when resized lose its ratio.

Per examples these images before(upper image) and after(the lower one) resizing:[image: Before resizing]  [image]
Clearly the secong image loses shape

I found this function(it's the answer to a previous thread):

```
def resize_image(self, image: Image, length: int) -> Image:
    """
    Resize an image to a square. Can make an image bigger to make it fit or smaller if it doesn't fit. It also crops
    part of the image.

    :param self:
    :param image: Image to resize.
    :param length: Width and height of the output image.
    :return: Return the resized image.
    """

    """
    Resizing strategy : 
     1) We resize the smallest side to the desired dimension (e.g. 1080)
     2) We crop the other side so as to make it fit with the same length as the smallest side (e.g. 1080)
    """
    if image.size[0] < image.size[1]:
        # The image is in portrait mode. Height is bigger than width.

        # This makes the width fit the LENGTH in pixels while conserving the ration.
        resized_image = image.resize((length, int(image.size[1] * (length / image.size[0]))))

        # Amount of pixel to lose in total on the height of the image.
        required_loss = (resized_image.size[1] - length)

        # Crop the height of the image so as to keep the center part.
        resized_image = resized_image.crop(
            box=(0, required_loss / 2, length, resized_image.size[1] - required_loss / 2))

        # We now have a length*length pixels image.
        return resized_image
    else:
        # This image is in landscape mode or already squared. The width is bigger than the heihgt.

        # This makes the height fit the LENGTH in pixels while conserving the ration.
        resized_image = image.resize((int(image.size[0] * (length / image.size[1])), length))

        # Amount of pixel to lose in total on the width of the image.
        required_loss = resized_image.size[0] - length

        # Crop the width of the image so as to keep 1080 pixels of the center part.
        resized_image = resized_image.crop(
            box=(required_loss / 2, 0, resized_image.size[0] - required_loss / 2, length))

        # We now have a length*length pixels image.
        return resized_image
```

I'm trying to insert it like this  `img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, preprocessing_function = resize_image` but it doesn't work because I'm not giving an `im`. Do you have any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) for providing custom functions to the ImageDataGenerator. It says and quote,

"**preprocessing_function:** function that will be applied on each input. The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape."

From the above documentation we can note the following:

When will this function be executed:

- after resizing image.
- after any data augmentation which has to be done.

Function argument requirements:

- only one argument.
- this argument is for only one numpy image.
- the image should be numpy tensor of rank 3

Function output requirements:

- one output image.
- **should be same shape as input**

This last point is really important for your question. Since your function is resizing the image it's output will not be the same shape as input and so you cannot do this directly.

One alternative to get this done is to do your resizing of dataset before passing to ImageDataGenerator.

Comment: Also the ImageDataGenerator will take care of calling this function, passing the image to it, getting the output and then finally returning the python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataframeIterator.